# SQL Query Issue - Fetching Rank and Position for a Specific Student

Tags: mysql

I'm currently working on a SQL query to retrieve the rank and position for a specific student based on their average score in a particular class, section, and session. However, I'm encountering an issue where the query only returns the top rank (1) when I include a WHERE clause to fetch details for a particular student.[image]

Here is my query

```
WITH RankedAverages AS (
    SELECT
        `student_id`,
        `class_id`,
        `section_id`,
        `session_id`,
        CAST(AVG(ft_tot_score) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS unique_average,
        TRUNCATE(AVG(ft_tot_score), 0) AS average_range
    FROM
        ftscores_primary
    WHERE
        `student_id`=870 AND 
        class_id = 9 AND
        section_id = 3 AND
        session_id = 19
    GROUP BY
        `student_id`,
        `class_id`,
        `section_id`,
        `session_id`
),
            RankedWithDenseRank AS (
                SELECT
                 `student_id`,
                      `class_id`,
                     `section_id`,
                     `session_id`,
                    unique_average,
                    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY average_range DESC) AS dense_rank
                FROM
                    RankedAverages
            ),
            RankedWithPositions AS (
                SELECT
                 `student_id`,
                      `class_id`,
                     `section_id`,
                     `session_id`,
                    unique_average,
                    CASE
                        WHEN RANK() OVER (ORDER BY unique_average DESC) = 1 THEN 1
                        WHEN RANK() OVER (ORDER BY unique_average DESC) = 2 THEN 2
                        WHEN RANK() OVER (ORDER BY unique_average DESC) = 3 THEN 3
                        ELSE dense_rank + 1
                    END AS position
                FROM
                    RankedWithDenseRank
            )
            SELECT
             `student_id`,
                      `class_id`,
                     `section_id`,
                     `session_id`,
                unique_average,
                position
            FROM
                RankedWithPositions
            ORDER BY
                position, unique_average DESC;
```

Without this WHERE clause `student_id = 870`, I get a nice table of ranks of students in a particular class. See image [image: rank table]

However, if I add the WHERE clause `student_id = 870`, It outputs 1 in the position column, but the real position is 4.

Can anyone help me identify the issue in my query or suggest an alternative approach to achieve the desired result? Any insights or corrections to the query structure would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make you query a subquery and do your `WHERE` in outside query.

Comment: thank you @PM77-1, did just that and it works well now

Comment: i think you can do that in one line try this 
SELECT rank()OVER(PARTITION BY class_id,
        section_id,
        session_id  
   order by CAST(AVG(ft_tot_score) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) desc) from students;

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did

```
WITH RankedAverages AS (
    SELECT
        student_id,
        class_id,
        section_id,
        session_id,
        CAST(AVG(ft_tot_score) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS unique_average,
        TRUNCATE(AVG(ft_tot_score), 0) AS average_range
    FROM ftscores_primary
    WHERE session_id = 19 AND 
    class_id =9 AND 
    section_id = 3
    GROUP BY student_id
),
RankedWithDenseRank AS (
    SELECT
        student_id,
        class_id,
        section_id,
        session_id,
        unique_average,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY average_range DESC) AS dense_rank
    FROM RankedAverages
),
RankedWithPositions AS (
    SELECT
        student_id,
        class_id,
        section_id,
        session_id,
        unique_average,
        CASE
            WHEN RANK() OVER (ORDER BY unique_average DESC) = 1 THEN 1
            WHEN RANK() OVER (ORDER BY unique_average DESC) = 2 THEN 2
            WHEN RANK() OVER (ORDER BY unique_average DESC) = 3 THEN 3
            ELSE dense_rank + 1
        END AS position
    FROM RankedWithDenseRank
)
SELECT
    student_id,
    class_id,
    section_id,
    session_id,
    unique_average,
    position
FROM RankedWithPositions
WHERE student_id = 870 
ORDER BY position, unique_average DESC;
```